# Sticky Side Bar on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a "sticky" side bar using this plugin: https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/jSticky. Basically, it works well on desktop but on touch devices it delays a second or two until the page is fully scrolled to re-appear in its proper place. Is there any way to make it scroll WHILE the page is scrolling as on desktop? I have seen sticky elements on other sites work like this, so there should be a way check and implement the position smoother. The code is below. All you do is assign a .sticky class to an item. For a demo, you can see this page I'm working on: http://www.mjmlawoffice.com/responsive/index.php/fees

```
<script>  
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(".sticky").sticky({
topSpacing: 0,
zIndex:2,
stopper: "#footer"
});
});
 </script>


;(function($) {

  $.fn.sticky = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        topSpacing: 0, // No spacing by default
        zIndex: '', // No default z-index
        stopper: '.sticky-stopper' // Default stopper class, also accepts number value
      },
      settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options); // Accepts custom stopper id or class

    // Checks if custom z-index was defined
    function checkIndex() {

      if (typeof settings.zIndex == 'number') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    var hasIndex = checkIndex(); // True or false

    // Checks if a stopper exists in the DOM or number defined
    function checkStopper() {

      if ( 0 < $(settings.stopper).length || typeof settings.stopper === 'number' ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    var hasStopper = checkStopper(); // True or false

    return this.each(function() {

      var $this          = $(this),
          thisHeight     = $this.outerHeight(),
          thisWidth      = $this.outerWidth(),
          topSpacing     = settings.topSpacing,
          zIndex         = settings.zIndex,
          pushPoint      = $this.offset().top - topSpacing, // Point at which the sticky element starts pushing
          placeholder    = $('<div></div>').width(thisWidth).height(thisHeight).addClass('sticky-placeholder'), // Cache a clone sticky element
          stopper        = settings.stopper,
          $window        = $(window);

      function stickyScroll() {

        var windowTop  = $window.scrollTop(); // Check window's scroll position

        if ( hasStopper && typeof stopper === 'string' ) {
          var stopperTop = $(stopper).offset().top,
              stopPoint  = (stopperTop - thisHeight) - topSpacing;
        } else if (hasStopper && typeof stopper === 'number') {
          var stopPoint = stopper;
        }

        if (pushPoint < windowTop) {
          // Create a placeholder for sticky element to occupy vertical real estate
          $this.after(placeholder).css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: topSpacing
          });

          if (hasIndex) {
            $this.css({ zIndex: zIndex });
          }

          if (hasStopper) {
            if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
              var diff = (stopPoint - windowTop) + topSpacing;
              $this.css({ top: diff });
            }
          }
        } else {
          $this.css({
            position: 'static',
            top: null,
            left: null
          });

          placeholder.remove();
        }
      };

      $window.bind("scroll", stickyScroll);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because your css selector for `@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
*js-mainnav.megamenu-sticky` is only displayed on a desktop with min-width 768px

the attribute that it needs are not on smaller browser are not included.

try adding

```
#js-mainnav.megamenu-sticky {
    z-index: 1000;
   position: fixed !important;
}
```

outside the mediaquery

Comment: no, sorry you are confusing the two different plugins. Megamenu-sticky is on top and I have no complaints about it. The problem is with the right-hand side bar, which is the contact form.

Comment: oh sorry i didnt know which one you were talking about.. did you check to see if the demo is has a delay?

Comment: actually after further review I found in the comments on github that this problem was identified by another user before, but I don't see that solution has been posted. If anyone can help improve via the jQuery script, great. If not, I'll have to look for another solution, unfortunately.

Comment: use another sticky http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/ and close this question as resolved!